# Parse saving in background best technique

Tags: swift, parse-platform, refactoring

I've struggling lately with my code readability and cleanliness and this is something I run into a lot. The following method runs fine and does everything that I need.

I've marked the line where my question arrises:

```
/**
     Creates a new `Group` and adds the currently logged in user as the `groupOwner`.

     - parameter name:       The name of the group
     - parameter completion: Called when the save request has completed passing back the newly saved `Group`. If an error occured it will be returned and `group` will be `nil`.
     */
    static func createNewGroup(name: String, completion:(group: Group?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {

        // Instantiate our new `Group`
        let newGroup = Group()
        newGroup.groupName  = name
        newGroup.groupOwner = User.currentUser()!

        newGroup.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) in

            // There was some problem saving the newGroup so return the error
            if let err = error {
                completion(group: nil, error: err)
            }

            // The newGroup was saved OK.
            else {

                // Now, since we've successfully saved the newGroup, we can append that to our current user.
                User.currentUser()!.ownedGroups.append(newGroup)

                //
                // HERE IS MY QUESTION
                //
                // Next up is the save the current user since he/she has been modified.
                User.currentUser()?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) in

                    // If there was some error saving the user, then we should delete the newGroup so it isn't hanging around in the db.
                    if let err = error {
                        newGroup.deleteInBackground()
                        completion(group: nil, error: err)
                    }

                    // Everything went OK some return our recently saved newGroup
                    else {
                        completion(group: newGroup, error: nil)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is should I be saving the current user with `saveInBackgroundWithBlock`? This method seems much more elegant and correct than the one above with nested blocks:

```
/**
     Creates a new `Group` and adds the currently logged in user as the `groupOwner`.

     - parameter name:       The name of the group
     - parameter completion: Called when the save request has completed passing back the newly saved `Group`. If an error occured it will be returned and `group` will be `nil`.
     */
    static func createNewGroup(name: String, completion:(group: Group?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {

        // Instantiate our new `Group`
        let newGroup = Group()
        newGroup.groupName  = name
        newGroup.groupOwner = User.currentUser()!

        newGroup.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) in

            // There was some problem saving the newGroup so return the error
            if let err = error {
                completion(group: nil, error: err)
            }

            // The newGroup was saved OK.
            else {

                // Now, since we've successfully saved the newGroup, we can append that to our current user.
                User.currentUser()!.ownedGroups.append(newGroup)

                // Save and return
                User.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
                completion(group: newGroup, error: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

However, it concerns me that in some random edge case, saving to the user in the background won't complete. Then I'll have this `Group` object hanging in my database and the user will also not see it the next time they load the app.

Are my fears here false or is my original method the proper way to go about constructing this function?

Answer (score 0):

I think your original method is just the right way. 
and one more thing, you need to show an activityindicator while saving in background.

Comment: I have these methods in a networking class so all the UI is done separately from these functions :)